Jenkins pipeline backup
I am running a jenkins server in an AWS EC2 instance of type t2.medium. I roughly have 20 pipelines with 1500 build history on an average for each pipeline and these pipelines are auto trigger from Github via a webhook. I want to backup the entire jenkins home directory and store in S3 bucket. I have shell script for backup mechanism and if I try to create a zip file and save on disk space before pushing it S3, will the ec2 instance be funtional ? Because I doubt the instance might go down becuase of capacity issues.
Any suggestions or inputs on this ?
Shell script I have used:
if ! command -v aws &> /dev/null; then
echo "AWS CLI is not installed. Installing..."
sudo apt-get install awscli -y
echo "AWS CLI has been installed."
else
echo "AWS CLI is already installed."
fi
echo 'tar $JENKINS_HOME directory'
set +e
tar -cvf jenkins_backup.tar.gz -C $JENKINS_HOME .
echo 'Upload jenkins_backup.tar to S3 bucket'
aws s3 cp jenkins_backup.tar.gz s3://jenkins-backup-test-bucket

What kind of size does the tar end up being?

With general estimates, which includes pipelines configurations, build histories and addon plugins along with default one, I guess it would be around 5GB approximately.

Then I don't see an issue with this. If it is 5 GB, you could also consider mounting an EFS and have the Jenkins home get zipped directly into the EFS without any additional steps.
